# BreakPointObserver Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

`Hello i am using the BreakpointObserver and try to emit 2 breakpoints. One for mobile and one for tablet. But the problem is it works for the Tablet but not for the mobile. In the switch statement it never reaches the mobile one.  Because i have tested it with console.log().

```
    private breakPointBehaviorSubject$ = new BehaviorSubject<Breakpoint>(Breakpoint.DESKTOP);

  constructor(private breakpointObserver: BreakpointObserver) {
    this.breakpointObserver.observe([ '(max-width: 800px)', '(max-width: 1200px)']).subscribe(result =>{
      const breakpoints = result.breakpoints;
      console.log(breakpoints);
      switch(true) {
        case breakpoints['(max-width: 1200px)']:
          this.breakPointBehaviorSubject$.next(Breakpoint.TABLET);
          console.log('Tablet ' + breakpoints['(max-width: 1200px)']);
          break;
        case breakpoints['(max-width: 800px)']:
          this.breakPointBehaviorSubject$.next(Breakpoint.MOBILE);
          console.log('Mobile ' + breakpoints['(max-width: 800px)']);
          break;
        default:
          this.breakPointBehaviorSubject$.next(Breakpoint.DESKTOP);
          break;
      }
     });
  }

  get breakpointObservable$()  {
    return this.breakPointBehaviorSubject$.asObservable();
  }
}`
```

Comment: What if you observed separately?

Comment: You need to put the `800px` case before the `1200px` case, because a mobile device is still less than 1200px, so that gets evaluated first.

Comment: @Steffan you should post that as answer

Comment: @Steffan i did but then it will emit only the mobile and not the tablet breakpoint. That's why i reversed it.

Comment: @Samir if you do that, then when width > 800, it should only do the 1200 case. that's strange

Comment: @Steffan you are right i changed the case back to Mobile and then Tablet, it emits both values now, but only one thing under 1200px  the navbar disappears and i see my hamburger menu, but under the 800px i see my navbar again. How can i prevent this.

Comment: @Samir not sure, as you only shared the part of your code that has to do with the breakpoint observer, so I don't know how the rest of your code works. do you have it on github or something?

Comment: @Steffan yes i have it on bitbucket

Comment: @steffan do you want to see my code

Comment: @Samir it's up to you if you want me to look at it. I can if you want

Comment: Here is the project on bitbucket. https://bitbucket.org/samir500/portfolio/src/master/

Comment: @Steffan I want to break  all pages on 1200px, but the workpage on 800px

Comment: @ObumunemeNwabude I tried that , with combineLatest() but I have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just change the condition and check the smallest one at first:

```js
const breakpoints = result.breakpoints;
console.log(breakpoints);

if (breakpoints['(max-width: 800px)']) {
  console.log("Mobile");
} else if (breakpoints['(max-width: 1200px)']) {
  console.log("Tablet");
} else {
  console.log("Desktop");
}
```

Comment: I have also used the if and else condition but I have the same problem.

Comment: Here is a working example, see what are doing wrong: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-breakpointobserver?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

So the issue is with the fact that the posted code blocks check for just one condition. But you want both conditions should report if that's the case.

Like in the switch statement you posted, because you are detecting for `true`, once the first case passes, the switch returns (because of the break statement). If you go ahead to reorder the cases, the same problem will be occurring. TypeScript doesn't permit fall through so switch won't be the solution.

If statements should solve this problem @ferhado's answer uses if-else blocks. This prevents one breakpoint from emitting if the other has emitted and technically is the same problem with switch. I tried editing but couldn't and had to paste this.

So use if statements independent of each other and you would be good. Something like the following

```
const breakpoints = result.breakpoints;
console.log(breakpoints);

if (breakpoints['(max-width: 800px)']) {
  this.breakPointBehaviorSubject$.next(Breakpoint.MOBILE);
  console.log('Mobile ' + breakpoints['(max-width: 800px)']);
}

if (breakpoints['(max-width: 1200px)']) {
  this.breakPointBehaviorSubject$.next(Breakpoint.TABLET);
  console.log('Tablet ' + breakpoints['(max-width: 1200px)']);
}
```

So any time the console logs 'Mobile true', expect it to equally log 'Tablet true'. The reason is when the device width is less than 800px, it is also less than 1200px. I suppose this solves the problem.

Comment: i tried the if statements but i have still the same problem. It breaks on 1200px to tablet but under 800px i see again my navbar instead.

Comment: Or do i need to create 2 observers with both their own subscriptions

Comment: I want to break on 1200px on all pages except my workpage it needs to break on 800px

Comment: "I want to break on 1200px on all pages except my workpage it needs to break on 800px". What do you mean by that statement. Please explain more. By breaking, do you mean that the navbar should be visible from 1200px upwards but then in the workpage you want it to be visible from 800px upwards ? explain better

Comment: under 1200px i break the navbar to a hamburger menu and change the styling of the pages. But on the workpage i want to break only the flexbox direction under 800px,.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem with two seperate observers, but i don't know if it is the right way.

```
private isMobile$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
  private isTablet$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

  constructor(private breakpointObserver: BreakpointObserver) {
    this.breakpointObserver.observe(['(max-width: 800px)']).pipe(map(breakpoint => {
      this.isMobile$.next(breakpoint.matches);
    })).subscribe();
    this.breakpointObserver.observe(['(max-width: 1200px)']).pipe(map(breakpoint => {
      this.isTablet$.next(breakpoint.matches);
    })).subscribe();
  }


  get breakpointMobile$() {
    return this.isMobile$.asObservable();
  }

  get breakpointTablet$() {
    return this.isTablet$.asObservable();
  }
```